# matplotlib legend: How to specify font weight?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

What is the best way to specify the font weight for a matplotlib legend? I can use:

```
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'legend.fontsize':12})
```

to set the font size but when I use

`matplotlib.rcParams.update({'legend.fontweight':'bold'`}

It complains that "'legend.fontweight' is not a valid rc parameter"

Answer (score 15):

You can pass parameters into `plt.legend` using the [`prop` argument](http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend). This dictionary allows you to select [text properties](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html#text-properties-and-layout) for the legend.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

legend_properties = {'weight':'bold'}

plt.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6], label='Test')
plt.legend(prop=legend_properties)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thanks for this answer! You can include the properties on the same line as the call to legend, like: `plt.legend(prop=dict(weight='bold')`

Comment: Is it possible to set this value in the mpstyle file?

Comment: ..also, if you like to set bold text for a specific legend record, you may enumerate `legend.get_texts()` and call appropriate `set_weight()` for each record.