# matplolib legend elements bold: font size too big

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, font-size, legend-properties

I have a plot and would like to have some things in my legend bold. Unfortunately if I do this then the font size of the bold text is bigger than that of the rest. How can I keep the font size the same but make it bold (without changing anything else)?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
fmt = '$%g$'
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
xticks = ticker.FormatStrFormatter(fmt)
yticks = ticker.FormatStrFormatter(fmt)
x1 = plt.scatter([1,2],[2,3], color='b')
x2 = plt.scatter([2,3],[4,3], color='r')
x3 = plt.scatter([1,3],[4,5], color='k')
x4 = plt.scatter(0, 0, color='white')
marker1 = 'marker 1'
marker2 = 'marker 2'
marker3 = 'marker 3'
plt.xlabel("x axis")
plt.ylabel("y axis")
marker4 = ('some text that needs to go here too'+'\n'+'and is very important and just way' +r'$\bf{\ too\ long\ }$' + 'so that it wont ever look good')
legend_two = plt.legend([x1, x4],[marker1, marker4],
                        fontsize=8,
                        title='some other title',
                        title_fontsize=10,
                        bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.0), #update
                        bbox_transform=fig.transFigure, # update
                        ncol=1,
                        loc="upper left",
                        borderaxespad=0)
plt.legend([x1,x2,x3], [marker1,marker2,marker3],
           fontsize=8,
           title=r'$\bf{some title}$',
           title_fontsize=10,
           bbox_to_anchor=(0.0, 0.0), # update
           bbox_transform=fig.transFigure, # update
           ncol=3,
           loc="upper left",
           borderaxespad=0)
plt.gca().add_artist(legend_two)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: A good answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537895/matplotlib-legend-how-to-specify-font-weight

Comment: The title of the legend on the left is set to the Latex Bold designation. Also, the font size is set to 10 while the font size of the legend on the right is 8. Changing these two will improve the situation.

Comment: @GiovanniTardini but this is only helpful if I want to do the whole legend in bold but not if I only want part of it in bold

Comment: @r-beginners how do you mean? one is fontsize and one is title_fontsize

Comment: The font size of the title was the same. What I wanted to say is the following. `plt.legend(...,fontsize=8, title='some title',title_fontsize=8,...)`